# Why has the cluster of text mined in R gone fuzzy?

Tags: text-mining, json, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, mongolite

Question: Why has the cluster dendrogram of text mined data gone fuzzy /messy (see link to the diagram below)?

Synopsis:I first harvested the original data of approximately 5500 e-scanned articles from a Mongo database, and saved in disk drive as a Json object (ode not shown here, harvested using Cran Mongolite package for R). What is shown here is the standard text processing (using Cran TM package) to clean “the”, “and”, “ing”, “;”, “:” etc.,). That lead to the ensuing hierarchical clustering, which looks fuzzy/MESSY because some of the words in the Json object were very long combinations of letters and not real words that can be separately identified.

Calling two of the libraries

```
library("tm")
library ("SnowballC")
```

Creating a path to the data and a corpus of text

```
cname <- file.path("C:", "texts")
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))
```

Processing the text

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation) 
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
```

Thirdly the clustering via dendrogram

```
d<-dist(tdm,method = "euclidean")
hc<-hclust(d, method="ward.D2")
library("rafalib")
myplclust(hc, labels=hc$labels)
```

**Link to the image:**
[cluster/dendrogram/text mining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsPBD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is cut less frequent words, more than just the standard stopwords that I had already done (see how I cut them in the code below)

`mystopwords <- findFreqTerms(tdm, 1, 20)
mystpwrds <- paste(mystopwords, collapse = "|")
tdm <- tdm[tdm$dimnames$Terms[!grepl(mystpwrds,tdm$dimnames$Terms)],]`

The whole picture and code is published here:

http://rpubs.com/antonyama/180574